# R: environment diagram for decorator function

Tags: r, function, scope, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I want to draw an environment diagram for the following code which contains an error to understand how R works exactly when evaluating a function.

```
# emphasize text
emph <- function(f, style = '**') {
  function(...) {
    if (length(style) == 1) {
      paste(style, f(...), style)
    } else {
      paste(style[1], f(...), style[2])
    }
  }
}

# function to be decorated
tmbg <- function() {
  'tmbg are okay'
}

# a decorator function with self-referencing name
tmbg <- emph(tmbg)
```

I got error while evaluating the call expression of the decorator function

```
tmbg()
> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

I could understand this is related to the lazy evaluation of function parameter in R. It feels like when evaluating `tmbg()` in global frame, the name of `f` used in the returned anonymous function binds again to `tmbg` in global frame which again returns the anonymous function and calls `f`, thus leads to infinite recursive calls. But this image is not so clear to me because I don't exactly know what is the evaluation model used in R especially with this "lazy evaluation".

Below I draw the essential parts of the environment diagrams and explain the evaluation rule used in **Python** for the equivalent code. **I hope to get such environment diagrams for R as well, or at least get the same level of clarity for the environmental model used in R.**

```
# This is the equivalent python code 
def emph(f, style = ['**']):
    def wrapper(*args):
        if len(style) == 1:
            return style[0] + f(*args) + style[0]
        else:
            return style[0] + f(*args) + style[1]
    return wrapper
    
def tmbg():
    return 'tmbg are okay'

tmbg = emph(tmbg)

tmbg()
```

When evaluating the assignment statement at line 12 `tmbg = emph(tmbg)`, the call expression  `emph(tmbg)` needs to be evaluated first. When evaluating the operator of the call expression, its formal parameter `f` binds to name `tmbg` in global frame which binds to a function we defined in global frame, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Next, after finishing the evaluation of the call expression `emph(tmbg)`, its returned function `wrapper` binds to the name `tmbg` in global frame. However the binding of `f` and the actual function `tmbg` is still hold in the local frame created by `emph` (`f1` in the diagram below).

Therefore when evaluating `tmbg()` in global frame, there won't be any confusion about which is the decorator function (`tmbg` in global) and which is the function to be decorated (`f` in local frame). This is the different part compared to R.

It looks like what R does is that it changes the binding from `f` -> `function tmbg()` to `f` -> name `tmbg` in global frame, which again binds to `function wrapper(*args)` calling `f` itself and thus leads to this infinite recursion. But it might also be a completely different model that R does not really bind `f` to any object but a name `tmbg` and ignores what that name represents. When it starts to evaluate, it looks for name `tmbg` and it finds the global one which is created by `tmbg <- emph(tmbg)` and gets infinite recursion. But this sounds really weird as the local scope created by the function call does not count anymore (or partially counts) for the purpose of "lazy evaluation" as soon as we pass an expression as argument of that function. There has to be then a system running parallelly other than the environments created by the function calls managing the namespaces and the scopes.

In either case, it is not clear to me the environmental model and evaluation rule R. I want to be clear on these and draw an environment diagram for the R code as clear as the one below if possible.

[image]

Comment: I think this is why the tidyverse uses tidy evaluation: See [this book](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) and how the function is wrapped using `as_mapper` [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/5aca9df41452f272fcef792dbc6d584be8be7167/R/output.R#L78)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not understanding environments. The problem is understanding lazy evaluation.

Due to lazy evaluation f is just a promise which is not evaluated until the anonymous function is run and by that time tmbg has been redefined.  To force f to be evaluated when emph is run add the marked ### force statement to force it.  No other lines are changed.

In terms of environments the anonymous function gets f from emph and in emph f is a promise which is not looked up in the caller until the anonymous function is run unless we add the force statement.

```
emph <- function(f, style = '**') {
  force(f)  ###
  function(...) {
    if (length(style) == 1) {
      paste(style, f(...), style)
    } else {
      paste(style[1], f(...), style[2])
    }
  }
}

# function to be decorated
tmbg <- function() {
  'tmbg are okay'
}

# a decorator function with self-referencing name
tmbg <- emph(tmbg)

tmbg()
## [1] "** tmbg are okay **"
```

We can look at the promise using the pryr package.

```
library(pryr)

emph <- function(f, style = '**') {
  str(promise_info(f))
  force(f)
  cat("--\n")
  str(promise_info(f))
  function(...) {
    if (length(style) == 1) {
      paste(style, f(...), style)
    } else {
      paste(style[1], f(...), style[2])
    }
  }
}

# function to be decorated
tmbg <- function() {
  'tmbg are okay'
}

tmbg <- emph(tmbg)
```

which results in this output that shows that f is at first unevaluated but after force is invoked it contains the value of f.  Had we not used force the anonymous function would have accessed f in the state shown in the first promise_info() output so all it would know is a symbol tmbg and where to look for it (Global Environment).

```
List of 4
 $ code  : symbol tmbg
 $ env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 $ evaled: logi FALSE
 $ value : NULL
--
List of 4
 $ code  : symbol tmbg
 $ env   : NULL
 $ evaled: logi TRUE
 $ value :function ()  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")= 'srcref' int [1:8] 1 13 3 5 13 5 1 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x00000000102c3730>
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Can I ask how the `env` attribute of the promise object is determined? If I omit the line with `force`, I got a promise with NULL value and global env. Is it determined by the current environment where I call `emp`?

Comment: If the promise has not been forced then env is the environment in which to evaluate the code and that would be the caller environment.  If the promise has been forced then the environment is no longer needed since the promise has a value so env is nulled out.

Comment: Another question is: does this env mean where to look for the symbol to update the value when the promise get evaluated? (for no force situation). Is evaluating a promise a same thing as evaluating its value? I mean as soon as the value of a promise is not NULL anymore, that value will get evaluated. If it is a function, it will be executed and return a value. If it is an expression, that expression will be evaluated. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, env is the environment in which to evaluate the code.  If the promise consists of a function definition then that function is the value of the promise once forced.  If the promise consists of a call to a function then that call is invoked returning its value once the promise is forced.  In both cases this is done with respect to the env environment.

Comment: Final question: You said "f is just a promise which is not evaluated until the anonymous function is run". Should it be until the name f is called to be more precise? It happens for my example that when anonymous function is called, the f is called as a consequence.

Comment: Yes, the promise is not forced until the promise is accessed.  If the function were run but f were not accessed in it then the promise would not be forced.